# sql query result null through postgres function

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm running a function that has parameters: 
- column name to display 
- column name on which the search is performed 
- value we are looking for

```
CREATE FUNCTION myFunction (column_1 varchar, column_2 varchar, 
myvalue varchar) returns varchar as $$
select distinct $1 from mytable where $2 = $3;
$$ language 'sql';
```

The result is always NULL. I tried with select INTO, RETURN ... etc but I still have null response

I tried a couple of syntaxes without success.
Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is what you need.

```
/* EXAMPLE PREPARATION */
drop table if exists mytable; 
create table mytable( a text, b text ); 
insert into mytable values ( 'aa', 'bb' ); 

select * from mytable; 
a  | b  
----+----
aa | bb
(1 row)

/* CREATE FUNCTION */
create or replace function myFunction (
  column_1 varchar, 
  column_2 varchar, 
  myvalue varchar) 
returns varchar 
as $$
declare
  r1 text;
begin
  execute 'select '|| quote_ident(column_1) || ' from mytable where '|| 
      quote_ident(column_2) || ' = $1'
    into r1
    using myvalue; 
  return r1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql; 

/* EXAMPLE USAGE AND OUTPUT */
select myfunction( 'b', 'a', 'aa' ); 

myfunction 
------------
bb
(1 row)
```

NOTES:

- Stored procedure using pgpsql, hopefully that is acceptable in your case
- Value to be used using bind variables (  *myvalue*  parameter value passed through  *$1*  )

  Used quote_ident() function, for security reasons

  More info in  [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)